# Script powershell import multiple CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a script to import CSVs (commands) that update the stock in SQL Server. But I encounter this error when I run the following script:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : La conversion de la valeur varchar '2200100001' a dépassé une colonne int.
>   L'instruction a été arrêtée.
>   Au caractère C:\Users\admin\Desktop\updateDb.ps1:36 : 19
>   + ...   $impcsv = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $db_name -Query $query -ServerIns ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Here is my powershell script:

```
$sql_instance_name = 'SERVER\SAGE100'
$db_name = 'SERVER_DB'
$table = "dbo.F_ARTSTOCK"

$csv_folder = 'F:\EUR'
$csv_completed_folder = 'F:\EUR\done'
$batchsize = 50000 

$csv_files = Get-Childitem -Path $csv_folder -Filter '*.csv'

$connectionstring = "Data Source=$sql_instance_name;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$db_name;" 
$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock) 
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = $table 
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0 
$bulkcopy.batchsize = $batchsize 

foreach($file in $csv_files) {
    $impcsv = $file.FullName

    write-host "Processing file ..........$impcsv" -foregroundcolor green
    $data = import-csv -Delimiter ";" $impcsv

    $count = 1

    foreach($i in $data) {

        Write-Host $i.Reference

        $reference = $i.Reference
        $quantity = $i.Quantity

        $query = "UPDATE dbo.F_ARTSTOCK (AR_Ref,AS_QteSto)
                SET dbo.F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto = dbo.F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto - $quantity
                WHERE dbo.F_ARTSTOCK.AR_Ref = $reference"
Write-Host $query
        $impcsv = invoke-sqlcmd -Database $db_name -Query $query -ServerInstance $sql_instance_name 

        write-host "Processing row ..........$count" -foregroundcolor green

        $count  = $count + 1

    }
}
```

Do you have any idea where the problem would come from?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post your error message  in English. Judging by the Google translation, it seems that you're trying to submit `2200100001` as a 32-bit integer, but that value is too large.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is in french. Translated it reads: The conversion of the '2200100001' varchar value has exceeded an int column. The instruction has been stopped.

Basically what that means is you have a 32-bit int column on that table and it needs to be of bigint type to handle a larger value... Or go through the data that you're trying to submit and verify that it is accurate (aka: remove that row from the csv. Depending on how sensitive of data you are working on).